# if statement jumping

Tags: c++, if-statement

If statement acting weird. For some reason if in the IF statement `if ( choosePositionX )` goes to else which tells the user the other player already made the move it goes into the next if `if ( choosePositionO )` and prints out the else in that one. How can I make it so once it goes to else in either if statement that it just breaks out and continues down. it seems that `break;` doesn't work.

Basically the else in the first once it gets used goes to the seconds else in the second if statement. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Initialize Array to 9 elements.
// Set array elements 1 to 9 to specify locations for placement of X and O.
char ticTacBoard[9] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

// gameState will return 1 to 4. #1. Player X has won, #2. Player Y has won, #3. Draw, #4. Game Not Finished.
int gameState = 0;
int choosePositionX = 0;
int choosePositionO = 0;
int totalMoves = 0;

// Functions declared to run game.
// Checks for winners, draw and if game should continue.
int checkGameState (int gameState);
// Takes in users moves.
void makeMove ();
// Resets board when game finished.
void reset ();
// Prints the board to the user.
void printBoard ();


int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!" << endl << endl
         << "The goal of Tic Tac Toe is to be the first player to get three in a row on the grid." << endl << endl
         << "Please select 1 through 9 to select placement for your turn."<< endl << endl;

    int gameState = 4;

    printBoard();

    while ( gameState == 4)
    {
        cout << "Player X please choose a position: ";
        cin >> choosePositionX;
        cout << endl;
        makeMove();
        totalMoves = totalMoves + 1;
        printBoard();
        gameState = checkGameState(gameState);
        if (gameState != 4)
        {
            if ( gameState == 1 )
            {
                cout << "Player X has won the game!" << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
            if ( gameState == 2 )
            {
                cout << "Player Y has won the game!" << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
            if ( gameState == 3 )
            {
                cout << "The game is a DRAW!" << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << "Player O please choose a position: ";
        cin >> choosePositionO;
        cout << endl;
        makeMove();
        totalMoves = totalMoves + 1;
        printBoard();
        gameState = checkGameState(gameState);
        if (gameState != 4)
        {
            if ( gameState == 1 )
            {
                cout << "Player X has won the game!" << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
            if ( gameState == 2 )
            {
                cout << "Player Y has won the game!" << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
            if ( gameState == 3 )
            {
                cout << "The game is a DRAW!" << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    char playAgain;

    cout << "Would you like to play again? y/n: ";
    cin >> playAgain;
    cout << endl;

    if (playAgain == 'y')
    {
        reset();
    }
    else if (playAgain == 'n')
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Thanks for playing!!";
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

void reset()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        ticTacBoard[i] = 49 + i;
    }

    gameState = 0;
    choosePositionX = 0;
    choosePositionO = 0;
    totalMoves = 0;

    main();
}

int checkGameState(int gameState)
{

////////////// CHECK FOR X /////////////////

    // Check Rows
    if(ticTacBoard[0] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[1] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[2] == 'X')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[3] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[5] == 'X')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[6] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[7] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[8] == 'X')
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Check Columns
    if(ticTacBoard[0] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[3] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[6] == 'X')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[1] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[7] == 'X')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[2] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[5] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[8] == 'X')
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Check Diagonally
    if(ticTacBoard[0] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[8] == 'X')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[2] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[6] == 'X')
    {
        return 1;
    }

////////////// CHECK FOR O /////////////////

    // Check Rows
    if(ticTacBoard[0] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[1] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[2] == 'O')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[3] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[5] == 'O')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[6] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[7] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[8] == 'O')
    {
        return 2;
    }

    // Check Columns
    if(ticTacBoard[0] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[3] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[6] == 'O')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[1] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[7] == 'O')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[2] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[5] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[8] == 'O')
    {
        return 2;
    }

    // Check Diagonally
    if(ticTacBoard[0] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[8] == 'O')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[2] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'O' && ticTacBoard[6] == 'O')
    {
        return 2;
    }

    // After 9 moves we call a Draw. Since we should have a winner before that.
    if ( totalMoves >= 9)
    {
        return 3;
    }

    // Otherwise CONTINUE
    else
        return 4;
}

void makeMove()
{
    if (choosePositionX)
    {
        if (ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'X' && ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'O' )
        {
            ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Player O has already made this move" << endl << endl;
            // keep same moves for counter draw
            totalMoves = totalMoves - 1 + 1;
        }
    }

    if (choosePositionO)
    {
        if (ticTacBoard[choosePositionO - 1] != 'X' && ticTacBoard[choosePositionO - 1] != 'O' )
        {
            ticTacBoard[choosePositionO - 1] = 'O';
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Player X has already made this move" << endl << endl;
            // keep same moves for counter draw
            totalMoves = totalMoves - 1 + 1;
        }
    }
}

void printBoard()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            cout << ticTacBoard[3 * y + x] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: why are `choosePositionX` and `choosePositionO` true at the same time?

Comment: I figured it out i had to set certain things to 0.

Comment: @mystycs - that's because choosePositionX is always true. You should try setting it to false sometime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot an `else` that connects your two `if`s. You need to use:

```
else if ( choosePositionO )
```

Comment: Well now it doesnt choose or go into choosePositionO at all.

Comment: @mystycs: that's because `choosePositionX` is always `true`.  You should try setting it to `false` sometime.

Comment: But will it work for the other one if the O would be true then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058397/if-statement-not-working-properly-choosing-both-else

Comment: @mystycs: can you do a `cout << choosePositionX << " " << choosePositionO << endl;` and see if that's working the way you intend it to?

Comment: Basically i have a cin for choosePositionX  and cin for choosePositionO. If the user cin for choosePositionX  and the if statement is true it runs the code in it. When the user cin for choosePositionO and the if statement is true it runs for the code for it. BUT in the event for those ifs choosePositionx and choosePositionO if its not equal then it should go to else and say this player blah blah already made this move. BUT my code ends up outputting both elses so it says it for both X and O.

Comment: @mystycs: can you update the question with the remainder of the code?

Comment: I pasted the entire code. Basically if you run it you will see you get both else statements outputted in each if in the void makeMove() function

Comment: I figured it out i had to set certain things to 0.

Comment: @mystycs: Post how you solved your problem as an answer here and accept it. This way, people can see how it was solved when they come by later.

Answer (score 4):

Use `else if`:

```
if (condition1)
{
  if (subcond1) { /* ... */ }
  else { /* ... */ }
}
else if (condition2)
{
  if (subcond2) { /* ... */ }
  else { /* ... */ }
}
else
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Then the condition 2 does not run for me in this

Comment: No - I thought you didn't want it to? Could you say more precisely what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Make the second `if` an `else if`, so if `choosePositionX` is true the `checkPositionO` won't be checked.

It looks like you could just use a single variable, if they are mutually exclusive. Or even better with an `enum`:

```
enum Player {
    PlayerX
  , PlayerO
};

enum Player choosePosition;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the second if(choosePosition)

```
    else if(choosePositionO)
```

then you can put a break